# Using async in a N-Tier Data Application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await, n-tier-architecture

The app I'm currently working on doesn't support asynchronous executions. 
My goal is to make a three layered n-tier synchronous app support asynchronous calls.

**Web**

```
[HttpPost("GetOrganisations")]
public OrganisationViewModel GetOrganisations([FromBody] GetOrganisationModel model)
{
    List<OrganisationModel> organisations = _organisationService.GetOrganisations(model?.Id, model?.StatusIds).ToList();

    return new OrganisationViewModel()
    {
        Organisations = organisations
    };
}
```

**Business**

```
public IEnumerable<OrganisationModel> GetOrganisations(int? organisationId, List<int> statusIds)
{
    return _organisationRepository.GetOrganisations(organisationId, statusIds).Select(m => m.ToModel()); //ToModel = Remapping to business model using extension
}

public static class OrganisationExtensions
{
    public static OrganisationEntity ToEntity(this OrganisationModel model)
    {
        if (model == null) return null;

        OrganisationEntity entity = Mapper.Map<OrganisationModel, OrganisationEntity>(model);

        return entity;
    }

    public static OrganisationModel ToModel(this OrganisationEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) return null;

        OrganisationModel model = Mapper.Map<OrganisationEntity, OrganisationModel>(entity);

        model.StatusName = entity?.Status?.Name;

        return model;
    }
}
```

**Data**

```
public IEnumerable<OrganisationEntity> GetOrganisations(int? organisationId, List<int> statusIds)
{
    IQueryable<OrganisationEntity> organisations = DB.Organisation.Include("Status").OrderByDescending(d => d.Created).AsQueryable();

    if (organisationId != null && organisationId > 0)
    {
        organisations = organisations.Where(o => o.Id == organisationId);
    }

    if (statusIds != null && statusIds.Count > 0)
    {
        organisations = organisations.Where(o => statusIds.Contains(o.StatusId));
    }

    return organisations;
}
```

### How would you make this code async?

The mapping extensions in the business layer is making this increasingly more difficult.

Is it necessary to "bubble up" the async/await calls all the way up?

### Let me give it a shot..

**Data**

```
public async Task<List<OrganisationEntity>> GetOrganisations(int? organisationId, List<int> statusIds)
{
    IQueryable<OrganisationEntity> organisations = DB.Organisation.Include("Status").OrderByDescending(d => d.Created).AsQueryable();

    if (organisationId != null && organisationId > 0)
    {
        organisations = organisations.Where(o => o.Id == organisationId);
    }

    if (statusIds != null && statusIds.Count > 0)
    {
        organisations = organisations.Where(o => statusIds.Contains(o.StatusId));
    }

    return await organisations.ToListAsync();
}
```

**Business**

```
public Task<IEnumerable<OrganisationModel>> GetOrganisations(int? organisationId, List<int> statusIds)
{
    return _organisationRepository.GetOrganisations(organisationId, statusIds).Select(m => m.ToModel());
}
```

> 'Task>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'Task>' could be found.

I know I can easily await the result at the business layer but wouldn't that be the incorrect way of using async? As I understand it I should await the result at the weblayer and somehow map data model to business model while using async.

Comment: "Is it necessary to "bubble up" the async/await calls all the way up?". Yes, as soon as you cut somewhere using `.Wait()` or `.Result` the method will still block.

Comment: use async if you have operations that are async. Is any of those operations really async ? or are blocking operations ? Does your ORM support async ? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/

Comment: @Gonzalo.- return await organisations.ToListAsync();

Comment: In your business code you need to have await `return await _organisationRepository.GetOrganisations(organ...`

Comment: @Niraj - But that would prevent me from bubbling up the async to the caller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't have to change mapping to make all calls async.
2. You are getting this error '*Task>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type '' could be found* because you need to await your call.

> ```
> public Task<IEnumerable<OrganisationModel>> GetOrganisations(int? organisationId, List<int> statusIds)
> {
>     return (await _organisationRepository.GetOrganisations(organisationId, statusIds)).Select(m => m.ToModel());
> }
> ```

3. You should name your async method like GetOrganisationsAsync.
4. You would also need to await at WebAPI layer. It would look something like this

> ```
>        [HttpGet]       
>         public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOrganisations(int? organisationId, [FromUri]int[] statusIds)
>         {
>            return OK(await _businessObject.GetOrganisations(organisationId,statusIds));
>         }
> ```

Comment: Should I not await the result at the webapi? Would it not loose "meaning" if I dont "bubble up" the async to the caller?

Comment: as others replied. you will need to wait all the way up till webapi layer. updated the answer.

Comment: So by using await in my business layer i might aswell go synchronous? If i had more database calls like this one in the web api i would still have to wait for every request in the business layer?

Comment: there is a difference between await and synchronous call. Synchronous call would block your thread waiting there while with await your thread is free to do other tasks.  I suggest you refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok. One final question before I accept your answer. Do you think this code design is bad for asynchronous calls? Would you do it differently? What I mean is, would this design cause and bottlenecks? Blocking any operations? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it would block any operation. This is a standard data - business - api layers design and with await all the way it would work just fine. I would change the naming of all async methods to end with Async though, it's a better practice from maintenance aspect.

Answer (score 2):

Async really needs to be all or nothing to be effective. If you have one blocking call anywhere down the call stack, your scalability more or less [gets ruined by that one thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

In terms of Entity Framework, it may be useful to have your data layer return an `IQueryable<T>` directly rather than returning a list. This could give you flexibility to upgrade your app in pieces instead of all at once.